# Buttons not visible under text and visible upper text

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I really dont know whats wrong with this.

In my DialogFragment i have easy layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--<ImageView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/screen_how_to_win"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:background="@drawable/screen_shot_info"-->
    <!--android:visibility="gone" />-->


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_text_lost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/you_lost"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_try_again"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/try_again" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_show_me_how_to_win"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/show_me_how_to_win" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Like u see, nothing specjal. But if my buttons is under TextView i didnt see them, but when i move button upper my TextView, then i see them. WTF? Im got blink black whole.

Here is my fragment:

```
 public class LostDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

//    @BindView(R.id.btn_show_me_how_to_win)
//    Button btnHowWin;
//    @BindView(R.id.screen_how_to_win)
//    ImageView screenWin;
//    @BindView(R.id.btn_try_again)
//    Button tryAgain;
//    @BindView(R.id.dialog_text_lost)
//    TextView textLost;

    public LostDialogFragment() {
    }

    public static LostDialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
        LostDialogFragment f = new LostDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lost_dialog_fragment, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
//        this.getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
//        configureShowMeHowToWinInfo();
        return view;
    }

//    @OnClick({R.id.screen_how_to_win, R.id.btn_try_again})
//    public void dismissDialogLostFragment() {
//        this.dismiss();
//        ((CurrencySelectActivity) getContext()).closerGameFragment();
//    }

}
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your xml TextView height from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`

Comment: Rofl u saved my day. Its time to take a break when i miss so much easy bug.